# Can't include state_machine in module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I'm attempting to use one state machine in two models and having them share it in a module

```
module Schedulable
 state_machine :state, initial: :unscheduled
end

class Install < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Schedulable
end
```

And I get the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `state_machine' for Schedulable:Module
```

How can i properly include the state machine from a module? I'm using the latest version of the `state_machines` gem

Comment: Do you mean you want the 2 models to share the same state machine *definition*, or share the same *definition and the same state*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state machine depends on ActiveRecord model so you need to make modules like concerns.

```
module Schedulable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    state_machine :state, initial: :unscheduled
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is a class that illustrates how to add behavior to a class by calling a method outside of that class.  You would need to replace the method definition with one that has the state machine code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module ModifyClass
  def self.add_foo_class_method(klass)
    class << klass
      def foo
        puts 'I am foo.'
      end
    end
  end
end

class C
  ModifyClass.add_foo_class_method(self)
end

C.foo # => "I am foo."
```

To translate this more to your context, I think it could look something like this:

```
module StateMachineAdder
  def self.add(klass)
    class << klass
      #  state_machine ...
    end
  end
end

class MyModel_1
  StateMachineAdder.add(self)
end


class MyModel_2
  StateMachineAdder.add(self)
end
```

Alternatively, you could define in a class in which the common behavior (such as the calls to state_machine in the class definition, and methods in both models containing identical or mostly identical behavior), and then have your 2 models subclass that class.  This might very well be the simplest solution.  For example:

```
class XyzModelBase
  state_machine ...

  # Any methods common to both base classes can go here
  def foo
    # ...
  end
end

class XyzModelFoo < XyzModelBase
  # ...
end

class XyzModelBar < XyzModelBase
  # ...
end

#
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want with my models as instances of the model don't have the state machine attached with them.

Comment: I was assuming that the state_machine method performs operations on (e.g. adds methods to) the class.  Isn't that true?  That's what `class << klass` does.

Comment: Where would StateMachineAdder.add get called? just anywhere in the class?

Comment: Without seeing the models and understanding exactly what behavior they have in common, it's difficult to recommend a specific strategy.  My approach is intended for cases where the state machine setup is done once in the class definition.  If there is more than this, then the inheritance approach I just added to the answer may be more appropriate.